GeoFence Bug in Codename One on Android
Hello Codename One Team!
I have been implemented a GeoFence feature. After recent changes to the Android build process for Codename One, I encountered a bug specifically on Android devices. The app crashes when adding a GeoFence while being inside the GeoFence area. This issue does not occur on iOS devices.
Issue Details:

The GeoFence works perfectly on iOS.
On Android, if I am outside the GeoFence location, the GeoFence is added without issues.
If I am inside the GeoFence location when adding the GeoFence, the app crashes with a message stating, "This app has a bug."

Geofence gf = new Geofence(fenceID, location, courtDiameter, -1);

try {
    LocationManager.getLocationManager().addGeoFencing(GeofenceWhoPlaysImpl.class, gf);
} catch (Exception eLoc) {
    UserInfo.setLogWP("Location! Add GeoFence error: " + eLoc.getMessage());
}


What could be causing the app to crash when adding a GeoFence while inside the GeoFence area on Android? How can I debug and fix this issue so that the GeoFence works correctly regardless of the device's current location?
I really appreciate any help you can provide. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Best Regards,
Oscar
2024-05-19 16:03:46.903  4970-4970  HoneySpace...lderFRView com.sec.android.app.launcher         I  updateCurrentPageOnLayout page=0
2024-05-19 16:03:49.704  2259-4617  SLocation               system_server                        W  GeopointGeofenceManager - refresh wifi to receive loc
2024-05-19 16:03:49.704  2259-4617  SLocation               system_server                        D  GeopointGeofenceManager - Location reported : fix method = 4 / 20.637
2024-05-19 16:03:55.954  2259-4617  SLocation               system_server                        W  GeopointGeofenceManager - refresh wifi to receive loc
2024-05-19 16:03:55.954  2259-4617  SLocation               system_server                        D  GeopointGeofenceManager - Location reported : fix method = 4 / 19.136
2024-05-19 16:03:58.048  2259-4381  ActivityManager         system_server                        D  Received SERVICE intent 0xbc5f472 Key{startService pkg=com.google.android.gms/geofencer_provider intent=act=com.google.android.location.internal.action.GEOFENCER_AR_RESULT pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.internal.PendingIntentCallbackService flags=0x2000000 u=0} requestCode=0 from uid 10237
2024-05-19 16:04:12.491  2259-6340  ActivityManager         system_server                        D  Received BROADCAST intent 0x31dc032 Key{broadcastIntent pkg=com.whosplays.app intent=act=com.codename1.location.backgroundlocationbroadcastreceiver.action.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE dat=http://codenameone.com/... cmp=com.whosplays.app/com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver flags=0x4000000 u=0} requestCode=0 sent=0 from uid 10237
--------- beginning of crash
2024-05-19 16:04:12.499  5954-5954  AndroidRuntime          pid-5954                             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.whosplays.app, PID: 5954
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent.hasError()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4905)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent.hasError()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver.java:134)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4896)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 
2024-05-19 16:04:17.511  2259-8082  ActivityManager         system_server                        D  Received BROADCAST intent 0x31dc032 Key{broadcastIntent pkg=com.whosplays.app intent=act=com.codename1.location.backgroundlocationbroadcastreceiver.action.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE dat=http://codenameone.com/... cmp=com.whosplays.app/com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver flags=0x4000000 u=0} requestCode=0 sent=0 from uid 10237
2024-05-19 16:04:17.665  6293-6293  AndroidRuntime          pid-6293                             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.whosplays.app, PID: 6293
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent.hasError()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4905)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent.hasError()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver.java:134)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4896)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 
2024-05-19 16:04:21.043  2259-2259  InputMetho...gerService system_server                        W  DexOnPCStateChangeObserver :  onChange(), keyboardState - 0 state 1
2024-05-19 16:04:30.688  2259-4617  SLocation               system_server                        W  GeopointGeofenceManager - refresh wifi to receive loc
2024-05-19 16:04:30.689  2259-4617  SLocation               system_server                        D  GeopointGeofenceManager - Location reported : fix method = 4 / 18.31
2024-05-19 16:04:36.220  2259-8082  ActivityManager         system_server                        D  Received BROADCAST intent 0x31dc032 Key{broadcastIntent pkg=com.whosplays.app intent=act=com.codename1.location.backgroundlocationbroadcastreceiver.action.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE dat=http://codenameone.com/... cmp=com.whosplays.app/com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver flags=0x4000000 u=0} requestCode=0 sent=0 from uid 10237
2024-05-19 16:04:36.227  6504-6504  AndroidRuntime          com.whosplays.app                    E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.whosplays.app, PID: 6504
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent.hasError()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4905)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent.hasError()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver.java:134)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4896)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

 

Can you connect the device with logcat and get the stack trace for the crash? Ideally for an unobfuscated build (debug build or with proguard disabled). You can edit the question to include this stack trace. Thanks.

@ShaiAlmog Thank you for your quick response. I edited the question and included the stack trace fatal error.

I made the following fix which should be available on the version released on May 24th 2024. However, I'm not sure if it will solve the problem since the line number in the stack isn't correct.
